# SQL Server 2017 Standard, CPU/MOP setting

Tags: sql-server, max, cpu

**Background**

2 **PHYSICAL** cluster nodes - each 4 sockets x 20 cores (80 logical processors), 1TB RAM

> 4 x Intel Xeon E7-8891 , 10 core(s), 20 Logical processor

Each one has 8~9 virtual **SQL Server 2017 STANDARD** instances, with current "max degree of parallelism" MOP settings from 2 to 4

Version Info

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU6) (KB4101464) - 14.0.3025.34 (X64)
>   Apr  9 2018 18:00:41   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation 
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 
>   (Build 9600: )

Now, I see warnings from sp_Blitz

> CPU Schedulers Offline    NULL    https://BrentOzar.com/go/schedulers 
>   Some CPU cores are not accessible to SQL Server due to affinity masking or licensing problems.
>
> Memory Nodes Offline  NULL    https://BrentOzar.com/go/schedulers Due to affinity
>   masking or licensing problems, some of the memory may not be
>   available.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/06/cpu-cores-or-memory-offline-the-problem-with-standard-edition-vms/

*Here’s the catch: the lesser of 4 sockets or 24/16 cores*

When I run below query (see results)

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers --115 total
 where status LIKE '%hidden%' --32 VISIBLE OFFLINE; 34 HIDDEN ONLINE
```

And Task Manager CPU graph is 20~30% overall on each node (maybe 24 are heavily used, rest not used, at 0-1% only, see image)
[image: Task Manager CPU by Logical processor]

I tried to search Error log for "Licensing" but cannot find such message indicating only some cores are used

**My questions**

1. Does "lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores" mean my SQL instance (EACH) will only use 24 cores (despite 80 available)?
2. What should my MOP setting be, per each Instance? 
   Are they smart enough to "share" the available CPU/NUMA? e.g. if there are 80 processors and 8 instances, they will not try to always use the first 24 processors

Current ones range from 2-4, but I think it should be at least 4

When I ran few Microsoft calculators, they all say 8

FYI: All instances are set to "Auto" set affinitiy/IO

Comment: Here's an excellent article in SQL 2017 Standard Edition restrictions https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-2019-standard-edition-licensing/ - answers your question 1 (yes 24 core limit). One other setting, along with MOP is Cost Threshold for Parallelism. If can help prevent everything that can go parallel from doing so, but it's usually on a case by case basis. Brent Ozar has excellent articles on this.

Comment: Off the topic, but to better utilize the resources, you really need to virtualize the server.

Comment: We do have VMware environment already, and may virtualize physical servers in future, but still need to address the current CPU issue :(

I am adjusting MAXDOP setting on each instance to monitor performance changes